# Restore ActionBar

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, device

I have this config for one activity

```
       <activity
        android:name="com.enterprise.app.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

But I need to show the ActionBar when is on tablets or some device with large resolution. Some tips or advice for this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create two styles, one in `values` and another in `values-sw600dp`.

**values style**

```
<style name="Your.Theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
```

**values-sw600dp style**

```
<style name="Your.Theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" />
```